# Help understanding proof for: Let $X$ be a set. Then $X \not\approx P(X)$ (where $\approx$ is equivalence relation)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In trying to understand the following proof, I am getting stuck on the chosen definition of $Y = \{ x \in X \mid x \not\in f(x) \}$. How do we know that such a set exists in $P(X)$ when we don't even really know what the function $f$ is?

[image: theorem]

Comment: By the way, $\approx$ is not just an equivalence relation. It's "equi-cardinality" relation, which is a very specific equivalence relation.

Comment: (Also it is usually a good idea to say what is the source of the proof that you didn't even type into the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that because we can write a formula with two variables, $\varphi(x,f)$ which is true if and only if $f$ is a function, $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and $x\notin f(x)$.

Then using bounded comprehension, the set $\{x\in X\mid\varphi(x,f)\}$ exists, and since it is a subset of $X$ by definition (all its elements were taken from $X$), this is an element of $\mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little lost. What is bounded comprehension?

Comment: It's that axiom (or rather a schema of axioms) that states that if $\varphi(x)$ is a formula (perhaps with parameters like in my answer) and $X$ is a set, then $\{x\in X\mid\varphi(x)\}$ is a set as well. This is also known as "Separation" or "Subset" axioms. Naively we would expect that if $\varphi(x)$ is a formula then $\{x\mid\varphi(x)\}$ is a set (this was called Comprehension axiom [schema]), but this was shown to be wrong by the various paradoxes of naive set theory such as Russell's paradox.

Comment: Also, what if it ends up that the function f is the one-to-one function such that f(x) = x.

Comment: First of all, is $x\in\mathcal P(X)$? Sometimes it is, sometimes it's not. But note that this set can be empty, or it can be equal to $X$ itself. Different functions give us different sets. The point is just that for a particular function, the set it defines is not in its range.